# SSL certificate wrong for site when accessed externally

Tags: ssl-certificate, outlook-web-app

A client has a OWA site and the SSL certificate for it is displaying the correct date when the site is viewed internally. However externally it displays a certificate that expired a year ago. The certificate has been removed from the server but it still displays it. IIS shows that the correct certificate is set in the bindings. <strike>Even more bizarrely is that it does not warn of an unsecured certificate when attempting to view the site.</strike>

EDIT: Turns out I had added an exception in Firefox to ignore the unsecured certificate

Comment: Presumably the connection's going through some other box on its way to the one you think it's talking to.  Trace the network, find the box.

Comment: This issue was escalated out of my hands but I did find out today that you were correct and that there was a TMG server in between.